# Signed Applets Without a Mixed Code Warning

Tags: java, wildcard, apache-commons

I build a signed applet to upload files from visitor computer, I used **WildcardFileFilter** class to get files that start with some string....

In-order to do this i needed to include Apachae Common io 2.4 jar file as library in my project, Now my Applet is signed but when i run it, It gives mixed code warning as show here

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html
```

Now i followed in instructions and added **Trusted-Library: true** in manifest file then it didn't loads that library and on running applet i got error **org/apachae/...../WildcardFileFilter** class not found.

I signed this common-io_2.4.jar library file then this warning went away But User prompted twice to accept applet which is annoying too...

How can i get trusted common-io file for using wildcard or some other advice......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, go to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) again and read the following:

Raising a warning is the default behavior, but there are options available to manage how this situation is handled.

•For users and systems administrators, various protection options are available. For more information, see Mixed Code Protection Options for Users.

•For developers and deployers, two manifest attributes are available. For more information, see Deploying Signed Applications and Applets Securely Without a Mixed Code Warning.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to include the name of the library (commons-io) in your class-path attribute in the manifest file. 
The other option is to extract commons-io package and jar it with your code, then signing it. This time you should only get the warning message one time.