# Signed Java applet suddenly has mixed code warning

Tags: java, applet, jarsigner

I have a signed applet on my website that had been working fine for nearly a year. Today, however, it's giving my users a mixed code warning. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929690/signed-applets-without-a-mixed-code-warning) that certain Apache components, which I happen to be using, can generate a mixed code warning. However, there are two things that concern me.

1. First of all, my applet consists of a single jar file that's signed, and when I use `jarsigner -verify my_signed_file.jar` I get the `jar verified` output. (It's not linking to any external libraries, all of the compiled code is inside this jar file.)
2. I'm getting this message all of a sudden, even though the my applet jar hasn't been modified in nearly a year. Both I and my client have been using the Java 1.7 runtime for a while now without getting this message, so why would we be getting the message today?

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

--Jay

Comment: Have you updated the JRE? I beleive a new version (update 21) was released recently, and it's possible that it's stricter about security now.

Comment: If you're doing xml parsing in your applet there is sometimes a HTTP request done to the server to find the XML Parser.

Comment: Further to @Antimony comment, see [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html).  This actually sounds like a slight glitch in that the message is nonsensical, but I'd bet 100 to 1 that you are both now using update 21.

Comment: In the latest update, Java no longer supports self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 7 Update 21, it displays a warning message when it encounters mixed code in your signed applet.

You need to add Trusted-Only: true attribute to your manifest file so it won't show a warning dialog.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html

Answer (score 0):

you have not made a .crt file to sign your jar with. please take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html
you need to make a .crt file within command prompt to use -jarsigner